# Can't find where segmentation fault occurs

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include "header.h"

char *ROOT = "/home/dereaper/Desktop/shared";

void getFolders (char *PATH, int i) {
    const char *path = PATH;
    DIR *dir = opendir(path);
    struct dirent *entry;
    while(entry = readdir(dir)) {
        if(!strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(entry->d_name, ".."))
            continue;
        printf("%s/%s INDEX:%d\n", path, entry->d_name, i);
        if(entry->d_type & DT_DIR) {  //check file type
            char *new_path;
            strcat(new_path, path);
            strcat(new_path, "/");
            strcat(new_path, entry->d_name);
            getFolders(new_path, i+1); //segmentation fault when calling recursevly

            // otherwise the program returns the correct output
        }   
    }
    closedir(dir);
}
```

Why am I getting segmentation fault?

Comment: Have you tried running gdb?

Comment: new_path is not initialized.

Comment: mm, perhaps he meant `strcpy` instead of `strcat` for the `strcat(new_path, path)` line

Comment: new_path is initiliazed, inside the if, remove const from `const char *path`

Comment: @CiMat: No, `new_path` is an uninitialized pointer so he is copying bytes to some unknown random address.

Comment: Please do not change the code of your original question after reading answers. Now your problem is that you only malloc a string of 1 char with no room for null terminator.

Comment: can you elaborate? how should I do this?

Comment: You want something like:
`char *new_path = malloc(sizeof(char)*(my_desired_string_length+1));`. Don't forget to free `new_path` when you're done.

Comment: You are probably not allowing enough memory. This should be another question. Your original question about the segfault caused by the unallocated string is answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype of the standard library function `strcat` is

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
```

Here, `dest` and `src` both are strings, they may not overlap and `dest` must be large enough for the string pointed by `src` to be appended to it.

In your code, in the statement

```
strcat(new_path, path);
```

`new_path` is a pointer to a character, not a string. It's not null terminated and not large enough for the string pointed to by `path` to be appended to it. `strcat` call attempts illegal memory access causing undefined behaviour and program crash due to segfault. You must allocate a buffer either dynamically or statically to concatenate strings to it.

```
#define MAX_LEN 40+1  // max buffer length. +1 for terminating null byte 

char new_path[MAX_LEN] = {0};  // initialize to null bytes

strcat(new_path, path);
// more strcat calls
```

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comment, the maximum buffer length is not known beforehand. In that case, memory should be dynamically allocated using `calloc` and `realloc`.

```
int size = strlen(path) + 1;
char *temp = NULL; // for holding new_path in case realloc fails
char *new_path = calloc(size, sizeof path[0]);
if(new_path == NULL) {
    printf("Not enough memory.\n");
    // handle it
}

strcat(new_path, path);
temp = new_path;
new_path = realloc(new_path, size *= 2); // double the size of the buffer
if(new_path == NULL) {
    printf("Not enough memory.\n");
    // handle it
}

// check if new_path is large enough for concatenation
const char *catstr = "somestring"; // string to be appended
if(size <= strlen(new_path) + strlen(catstr)) {
    // allocate more memory
    temp = new_path;
    new_path = realloc(new_path, size *= 2); // double the buffer size
    if(new_path == NULL) {
        printf("Not enough memory.\n");
        // handle it
    }
}

strcat(new_path, catstr);

// and so on
```

This gets unwieldy with all the checks for `NULL` but there's no easy way out when you deal with dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: MAX_LEN is unknown and can be very very long so a fix value wont do

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu I have updated my answer for this. Please have a look.

Comment: @downvoter why do you downvote without leaving a note? what purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 5):

```
char *new_path;
strcat(new_path, path);
```

Is undefined behavior.

There is no memory for strcat to append to since new_path is uninitialized and unallocated. strcat appends to an undeterminated address, creating a segfault.

Comment: I've allocated new_path but it still says segfault